# Grails deployment on Google App Engine blocked by Unresolved Dependencies during grails install-plugin app-engine

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am following the steps described in this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wP-aZdXymro to deploy my grails application on GAE. I am runnning Grails-2.2.0 and I have uninstalled the hibernate plugin. However, when I try to install the app-engine plugin, I get the following message -

```
==> grails install-plugin app-engine
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for     more information):

- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:1.0.0.RELEASE
- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-jpa:1.0.0.RC3
- org.grails:grails-datastore-jpa:1.0.0.RC3
- org.grails:grails-datastore-web:1.0.0.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use install-plugin, it's deprecated. Remove all plugins from your application.properties. Then, add this to your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile ":app-engine:0.8.10"
```

Afterwards you can check what plugins are still requiring the datastore plugin (if any):

```
 dependency-report
```

Answer (score 1):

Grails doesn't work well with GAE. You're much better off either using Gaelyk ( https://gaelyk.appspot.com/ ) if you want to take advantage of Groovy syntax, or deploy your Grails application to a more traditional cloud provider like Heroku, Cloudbees, AWS, etc.